# Remove only leading repeating characters if occurs more than 4 times in string

Tags: java, regex, string

The repeating characters can be anything `[a to z]`, `[0 to 9]` or any special characters.

For example:

```
String a = "CCCCCCgshdbuasvbd";
```

Consider `C = [a to z],[0 to 9]`, or anything like `~!@#$%*&()_-><?`.

I need to remove the "any repeating leading characters in string if that occurs more than 4 times" in the string.

How can I accomplish this using a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
str = str.replaceAll("^(\\S)\\1{3,}", "");
```

#### [Working Demo](http://regex101.com/r/gY1rC6)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

Search: `^(.)\1{3,}`
Replace: `<NOTHING>`

This will replace any character at the beginning of the string, present 4 or more times, by nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use java's regex based replaceAll() method. The regex should start (`^`) by allowing any letters and numbers (`[a-Z0-9]`)

You then know whichever char it starts with needs to be repeated at least 3 more times (`{3,}`)

you are replacing anything that matches with empty string (ie deleting it)

```
str = str.replaceAll("^([a-Z0-9])(\\1){3,}","");
```